# facebook auth dialog return The page you requested was not found instead of redirect back to my activity?

Tags: android, facebook

When trying to login to my app that was working perfectly in the past I can login and then I see `The page you requested was not found` in the auth dialog instead of redirect back to my activity. I know this is an issue with Facebook.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem last month for about 20 hours and then it was solved. To see if it's Facebook's problem go to your app dashboard on developers.facebook.com and try to edit the settings. if you're getting errors there you'll have to wait until it gets solved.

Facebook usually pushes updates on Tuesday/Wednesdays so it might be solved quickly.

Comment: I add settings for App on Facebook and add url for our website and it worked fine after that. It's wrong thing to do but it worked for now

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The resolution ended up being changing the second argument passed to the `dialog(...)` method to `"feed"` instead of `"publish.stream"`. Like so:

```
facebook.dialog(StoryActivity.this, "feed", params, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
    // Overridden methods
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. The solution ended up being changing the second argument passed to the `dialog(...)` method to `"feed"` instead of `"publish.stream"` like so:

```
facebook.dialog(StoryActivity.this, "feed", params, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
    // Overridden methods
});
```